# Event tagging on plots in PyQt

Tags: qt, plot, pyqt4

I was wondering how to put event tags at the bottom of plots (x-axis) to signify that something had happened at that time point. As far as I know, this feature is not available in PyQt nor in Matlablib. Any advice would be very much appreciated!